# TypeError: functions.pubsub.schedule is not a function

Tags: firebase

Getting this problem deploying a scheduled function on firebase:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: functions.pubsub.schedule is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alacret/workspace/kadem-functions/functions/index.js:12:46)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:15:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:53:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching over the internet for a while I couldn't find an answer, not even reviewing Firebase docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

The problem was with my `firebase-functions` version, I have it setup to:

`firebase-functions:2.2.0`

and it needs to be at least `2.3.0` on your package.json