# Cloud function does not trigger when time has come

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making a simple app for Google Play. I wrote the function for trigger at the time to show the user fcm. The time is passed but my function is not triggered. I clicked to run the query. But It does not happen. How can I fix it ?
The time is UTC+3 01:48 (Turkey)

Here is my code :

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.secondtification = functions.pubsub.schedule('48 1 * * *').
timeZone("Turkey")
  .onRun(async (context) => {

    // Don't forget to activate cloud messaging in your application.

    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: "Tunaydin",
        body: "Bir bardak su içme vakti."
      }
    }

    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("users", payload)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log("Notification sent ", response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error sending notification: ", error);
      });
  });
```

My code is not triggered when time is passed. Also, My cloud console never shows me anything.

Answer (score 1):

Please be sure that your function is deployed. If it is, you could see the log on the GCP console. It could be seen whether there's something wrong or not from your function from the log.

Comment: I do not know why. When I upload to the my code. VS code is shows me: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: functions.schedule is not a function

Comment: IMO it relates to the library issue see: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57446811/typeerror-functions-pubsub-schedule-is-not-a-function)

Comment: So? How can I update my library? I am a newbie. Or What I should write to the library version?

Comment: You could specify the packages that you want to use on the package.json inside your cloud function seet [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs)

Comment: I do not get it. What should I do ? What do I write to package.json ?